# Child process exited with code 1 LibGDX jPackageImage task

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, child-process, gradle-plugin, jpackage

I am using jpackage to convert my libgdx game to an executable file. I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqbW1mUXBEUnhyNFA2RFlfZmJOaWlPLTNhYjZwZ3xBQ3Jtc0tuUDhLbXdrQ0RHZl9laHF2ZkRtVXBFcXhITkxmRnEwZVZJTVJzVThLR3FucXZjR2x2eWdWZE5qLVVuR2FRRkcyRkRBM1IxUWpWZDBQam1za2pseU9udGVEZWE4OG9UY3VLbk5nSnAxZ1hpcU5manhvUQ&q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fraeleus%2Fskin-composer%2Fwiki%2FDeploying-libGDX-with-jpackage-and-Badass-Runtime&v=R7CMXeQ11GM) to do so. The jpackageImage task works perfectly fine but when the exe is created and I run it, it doesn't run but rather gives me an error: `Child process exited with code 1` I am unaware what is causing this.
I am on windows 11 and im using JDK 18.0.1.1.
The JDK is set to `JAVA_HOME` which is set to the correct PATH.
I am using Badass-Runtime plugin as well which is defined in the first line of my build.gradle file.
Here is my build.gradle file for desktop:

```
plugins { id 'org.beryx.runtime' version '1.8.4' }
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ["src/"]
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = ["../core/assets"]

mainClassName = "com.mygdx.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher"
def osName = System.getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../core/assets")

task runGame(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
}

task debug(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
    debug = true
}

task dist(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
    dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    with jar

    destinationDirectory = file("$buildDir/lib")
}

jpackageImage.dependsOn dist

dist.dependsOn classes

eclipse.project.name = appName + "-desktop"

runtime {
    options = ['--strip-debug',
               '--compress', '2',
               '--no-header-files',
               '--no-man-pages',
               '--strip-native-commands',
               '--vm', 'server']
    modules = ['java.base',
               'java.desktop',
               'jdk.unsupported']
    distDir = file(buildDir)

    jpackage {
        jpackageHome = 'C:\\Users\\pc\\.jdks\\openjdk-18.0.1.1'
        mainJar = dist.archiveFileName.get()
        if (osName.contains('windows')) {
            imageOptions = ["--icon", file("../icons/icon.ico")]
        } else if (osName.contains('linux')) {
            imageOptions = ["--icon", file("../icons/icon.png")]
        } else if (osName.contains('mac')) {
            imageOptions = ["--icon", file("../icons/icon.icns")]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it this bug? bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8284067 which triggers because your code exits with 1. Try doing with System.exit(0); , there is a workaround listed as well.

Comment: Oh thanks but I just switched to Packr and it worked.